# Android 12 and higher are required

Tags: androidexported

I'm developing an app. There are no coding errors in my app, however when I try to build with defaultTargetSdkVersion=30,
everything works properly and I can generate the APK, but I can't submit it to the Play Store since it displays the following warning:
updated the  30 to 31
defaultTargetSdkVersion=31 added android:exported at mainfest.xml,

but still mainfestmerger showing the error
Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 33 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs

please suggest

I have made the changes on Androidmainfest.xml added android:exported ="true"